# How do I get two horizontal divs to stack on top of each other for mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two divs on one of my pages that are side by side, and when shrunk down for mobile, I need them to stack on top of each other, and I just cant figure out why it isn't working. I have some @media code I was trying out, but it isn't doing anything. Would really appreciate some help on this, thanks in advance!

Here's the html for the divs:

```
 <div id="page3">
            <div id="left3">
              <img src="images/entertowin_03.png">
                <h4>•text<br>•text<br>•text<br></h4>
            </div>

            <div id="right3">
            <img src="images/winnermap_06.png">

            </div>



        </div>
       <div id="dog">
        <image src="images/barrybottom_04.jpg"></image>
           <h3><a href="#neheader" class="class1">Back to top</a></h3>
        </div>
```

and the css I have...

```
#page3 {
       background-image: url("../images/page3back_01.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;


    min-height: 600px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 2em;
    display: flex;
    overflow:hidden;


}


#left3 {
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    max-width: 440px;
    height: 330px;
    display: block;
    flex: 0 0 65%;



}



#right3 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    max-width: 440px;
    height: 330px;
    display:block;
    flex: 1;
    padding-top: 7%;


}
```

and then this was the code I found for the responsive media query that I cant get to work:

```
/** Responsive **/


#left3 {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left; 
  margin-right:20px;
  width:140px;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
}
#right3 { 
  background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  border:2px dashed #ccc;
  min-height:170px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #left { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

float both divs left (and clear the container), making them 50% width (or whatever to equal 100%) in desktop.  then in the media query, keep them floated, but just make their widths 100%

```
#page3 {
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    /*All of your other styles */
}
#left3 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    /* All of your other styles */
}
#right3 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    /* All of your other styles */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px)   {
    #left3, #right3 {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't do anything. could there be something in the code that I have that is preventing it from working?

Comment: It could be the use of 'screen' in the media query.ive removed scree and, and updated the query. Try that. If that still doesn't work, change max-width to min-width